# Free Windows software to schedule upload to FTP server

Tags: ftp, scheduled-tasks

i am searching for a software like turboftp, it allows me to setup sheduled tasks and upload some folder to my ftp folder.

Important is, it must be free.

I have a lot of files in this folder, so i just need to upload *.pdf files.

If some one have an idea for a batch file, let me know.

Thx

Comment: is the windows built in FTP client and windows task scheduler inadequate? If so, in what ways would a proposed client have to be better?

Comment: maybe but i have no idea how to setup such task...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about [fling](http://www.nchsoftware.com/ftp/index.html)?
Looks like it's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

What about CURL?

http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/320/using-curl-to-access-ftp-server/

I use it for http downloads a lot, but just found out it can do FTP, too. It is also available for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Batch files can do this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/

This should get you started :)

Answer (score 1):

I use wput in a batch file, triggered via the task scheduler. That's about as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe easier: Use the FileZilla command line: http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_%28Client%29

Comment: there no good commands :(

Comment: That only fires the GUI, it doesn't actually send or receive any files once the GUI is opened, so that doesn't help much.